# Calling a f:ajax keydown event but only when the left arrow key is pressed

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there a good to make it so the following event only call the ajax request on the left arrow and acts normally otherwise.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="menuId" value="#{bean.value}" converter="entityConverter">
        <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="All Categories"/>
        <f:selectItems  value="#{bean.valueList" var="value" 
            itemLabel="#{value.subcatName}" itemValue="#{value}"/>
            <f:ajax event="keydown"
                    listener="#{bean.goBack()}"
                    execute="@this"                                 
                    render="@form"
                    onevent="function(data) { if (data.status === 'begin') { //is there something I can do here?}}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 3):

As you seem to be using Primefaces, take advantage of its [`p:remoteCommand`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml) utility. It creates a javascript function which can be used to make ajax requests. For your case it could be:

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SelectionBean implements Serializable {

    private List<String> values = Arrays.asList("val1", "val2");

    private String selection;

    public String getSelection() {
        return selection;
    }

    public void setSelection(String selection) {
        this.selection = selection;
    }

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void goBack() {
        System.out.println("Going back...");
    }

}
```

```xhtml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head />

<h:body>

    <h:form>
        <p:remoteCommand name="goBack"
            actionListener="#{selectionBean.goBack}" />
        <script>
            function processKey(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 37) {
                    goBack();
                }
            }
        </script>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectionBean.selection}"
            onkeydown="processKey(event);">
            <f:selectItems value="#{selectionBean.values}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Here we use an auxiliary JS function which checks if the event keyCode is the one for the left arrow. If true, call the Primefaces generated JS function which will trigger the server side method.

Comment: Thanks Xtreme, it is looking like that may be what I have to do. We have been trying to avoid primefaces as much as possible just because it seems to have a fairly large performance impact, but this should work.

Comment: @Landister, I tested the solution before posting it with PF 4 and Mojarra 2.1.28. PF is already in its 5.0 version, so I think it's a mature enough framework to use, with a lot of bugs being fixed from stage to stage. Obviously it loads CSS styles and images and also a JS file, but IMO nothing it should worry you if you properly enable cache browsing in production environments.